# What should be the value of Path in AWS GetParametersByPathRequest to retrieve Parameters from the Parameter Store

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

We are using the following code to get parameters from the AWS  Parameter Store:

```
AWSSimpleSystemsManagement client = AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.standard().build();
    GetParametersByPathRequest request = new GetParametersByPathRequest();
    request.setWithDecryption(true);
    request.setPath(path);
    GetParametersByPathResult result = client.getParametersByPath(request);
    List<Parameter> params = result.getParameters();
```

The parameters are listed in the table below.  However, I cannot find the path value request.setPath(path) to retrieve at least one parameter, what could be the value?

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Name</th><th>Type</th><th>Desctiption</th><th>Key Id</th></tr><tr><td>/dev/sumologic/access_key</td><td>SecureString</td><td>Sumologic access key</td><td>alias/aws/ssm</td></tr><tr><td>/dev/sumologic/accessid</td><td>SecureString</td><td>Sumologic access id</td><td>alias/aws/ssm</td></tr><tr><td>/dev/threatstack/key</td><td>SecureString</td><td>Threatstack key</td><td>alias/aws/ssm</td></tr><tr><td>Alex1</td><td>String</td><td>Alex1Test</td><td>-</td></tr><tr><td>Alex2</td><td>String</td><td>Alex2description</td><td>-</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: the recommendation is to use keys with / in the path so either the "name" field or the "Key Id" field as these both have / in them.  Just try it and see what happens

Comment: @Vorsprung, what recommendation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key was to add the recursive option:

```
request.setRecursive(true);
```

Then path="/dev/" will retrieve all parameters starting from "/dev"
If we do not want to add the Recursive option then the path should be /dev/sumologic/ to retrieve the 3 level parameters starting from /dev/sumologic/. For one-level parameters the path is "/"

Answer (score 0):

I have aws java SDK 1.11 but it does not provide "GetParametersByPathRequest" when adding
import com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.model.GetParametersByPathRequest     cannot be resolved

I have added AWS Java SDK V2 to Pom file as follows,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-sdk-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.16.60</version>
```

but again it raise error when creating GetParamaterByPathRequest

```
GetParametersByPathRequest paramsRequest = new GetParametersByPathRequest(null).withPath(/)
            .withRecursive(true).withWithDecryption(true);
```